# C# MVVM pattern sanity check

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am needing to get a sanity check to make sure I am setting up my model and viewmodel correctly. I believe what I have is correct even though I have seen some documentation that shows different ways this can be done. I posted two examples of my code below. Any hints or suggestions are always appreciated.

Model:

```
namespace StewLedger.Model
{
 public class AccountModel : IDisposable
{
private Connection conn = new Connection (ConnectionString.connectionString);
private bool disposed = false;
private SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
private AccountVM  accountVM = new AccountVM();
private AccountTable accountTable = new AccountTable();


public bool AddNewAccount(AccountVM account)
{

    if(conn.NonQueryCommand(accountTable.AddAccount(account.AccountType, account.AccountName, User._username, account.BankId, account.AccountNumber, account.StartingBalance, account.Balance)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public Accounts LoadAccounts()
{
    List<string> o = conn.QueryCommand(accountTable.GetAccounts(User._username));
    Accounts accounts = new Accounts();

    int numRecords = 0;

    numRecords = o.Count / 7;

    int item = 0, item1 = 1, item2 = 2, item3 = 3, item4 = 4, item5 = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++)
    {
        AccountVM accountVM = new AccountVM
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt16(o[item]),
            AccountName = o[item1],
            AccountType = o[item2],
            Balance = Convert.ToDouble(o[item4]),
            StartingBalance = Convert.ToDouble(o[item3]),
            AccountNumber = o[item5]
        };

        item += 7;
        item1 += 7;
        item2 += 7;
        item3 += 7;
        item4 += 7;
        item5 += 7;
        accounts.addAccount(accountVM);
    }

    return accounts;
}


public bool UpdateBalance(double balance, int id)
{
    AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();

    if (conn.NonQueryCommand(accountTable.UpdateBalance(User._username, balance, id)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void SelectAccount(DashBoardView dashBoard)
{
    AccountVM accountVM = (AccountVM)dashBoard.gridAccounts.SelectedItem;
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    Accounts accounts = LoadAccounts();
    LedgerModel ledgerModel = new LedgerModel();

    if (accountVM != null)
    {

        transaction =ledgerModel.LoadLedger(accountVM.Id, accountVM.AccountName);

        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (accounts[i].Id == accountVM.Id)
            {
                accountVM.Balance = accounts[i].StartingBalance;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < transaction.Count; i++)
        {

            transaction[i].Balance = ledgerModel.CalculateBalance(Convert.ToDouble(accountVM.Balance), transaction[i]);
            accountVM.Balance = transaction[i].Balance;

        }

        if (transaction != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < transaction.Count; i++)
            {
                if (transaction[i].TransType == "Withdrawal")
                {
                    transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
                else if (transaction[i].TransType == "Deposit")
                {
                    transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SteelBlue);
                }
                else
                {
                    transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }
            }

            dashBoard.gridLedger.ItemsSource = transaction;

        }
    }
}

public void DeleteAccount(DashBoardView dashBoard)
{
    AccountTable accountTable = new AccountTable();
    LedgerTable ledgerTable = new LedgerTable();
    AccountVM accountVM = (AccountVM)dashBoard.gridAccounts.SelectedItem;



    using (Connection conn = new Connection(ConnectionString.connectionString))
    {

        TableInfo tableInfo = new TableInfo
        {
            Id = accountVM.Id,
            Owner = User._username,
            TableName = "Accounts",
            T = TableInfo.Table.ACCT
        };

        conn.NonQueryCommand(accountTable.RemoveRow(tableInfo));
        if (conn.TableExist(User._username + accountVM.AccountName + "Ledger") == true)
        {
            conn.NonQueryCommand(ledgerTable.DropTable(User._username, accountVM.AccountName));
        }
        dashBoard.gridAccounts.ItemsSource = LoadAccounts();

    };
}


public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(false);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Free managed resources
    if (disposing)
    {
        handle.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

    disposed = true;
 }
}


}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace StewLedger.ViewModel
{
public class AccountVM : Notifier
{
private string _accountType;
private string _accountName;
private string _accountNumber;
private double _balance, _startingBalance;
private int _Id;
private int _bankId;

public int Id { get => _Id; set { _Id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); } }
public string AccountType { get => _accountType; set { _accountType = value; OnPropertyChanged("AccountType"); } }
public string AccountName { get => _accountName; set { _accountName = value; OnPropertyChanged("AccountName"); } }
public double Balance { get => _balance; set { _balance = value; OnPropertyChanged("Balance"); } }

public int BankId { get => _bankId; set { _bankId = value; OnPropertyChanged("BankId"); } }

public string AccountNumber { get => _accountNumber; set { _accountNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("AccountNumber"); } }

public double StartingBalance { get => _startingBalance; set { _startingBalance = value; OnPropertyChanged("StartingBalance"); } }
}


public class AccountTypes : ObservableCollection<string>
{
public AccountTypes()
{
    this.Add("Checking");
    this.Add("Savings");
    //Add credit and loans later will require seperate setup
}
}

public class Accounts : ObservableCollection<AccountVM>
{

public Accounts()
{

}
public void addAccount(AccountVM vM)
{
    this.Add(vM);
}

public ObservableCollection<AccountVM> GetAccounts()
{
    return this;
}

public void deleteAllAccounts()
{
    this.Clear();
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Exact _requirements_ for VM depend on UI framework you're using but a reference to VM inside the model is surely a smell. Actually your model is doing VM things and manipulating directly the view. After that we can talk about micro design.

Comment: This Model pretty much access and manipulates the database. There is a database connection class, tables classes, etc. My understanding of the ViewModel is that it pretty much holds data items that can be observed by the view and the model is any code that does something with those data items.

Comment: Using C# and WPF. The MVVM is rolled be me, I am not using Prism or anything like that.

Comment: How is this model being used? That is, where is the code that calls those `LoadAccounts`, `UpdateBalance` and `SelectAccount` methods?

Comment: It depends, for instance addNewAccound adds a row to the database and  LoadAccounts returns a list of accounts from the database . They are located where they are needed. Methods like Delete and SelectAccount are methods for button events. After doing more research I think I see where I fundamentally went way off of the rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### MVVM

MVVM is normally structured as following:

```
  View     // user interface
   ↑ ↓
Viewmodel  // handles user interaction, makes data ready for display, 'glue' layer
   ↑ ↓
  Model    // actual business logic
```

Views display data taken from view-models, and send user input back to view-models (in WPF this happens via data and command bindings). View-models don't reference views directly, but notify them about data updates via events (`INotifyPropertyChanged`).

View-models operate on models (often in reaction to user input) and make data (extracted from models) ready for display and interaction. Models don't know about view-models, but (if necessary) can raise events that view-models can react to.

This makes the model reusable in different contexts (console application, service, server-side, etc.) and you can write tests for it without having to fiddle with UI automation.

### Your architecture

In your case, the model directly operates on views and view-models, and those view-model classes are used as if they're part of the model layer. This makes the model difficult to reuse and to test, and there's an increased risk that UI changes will break something or require additional model changes.

Here's roughly how I would structure your code (various things omitted for clarity):

```
DashBoardView (DataContext -> DashBoardViewModel)
  - accounts list-view (ItemsSource -> Accounts, SelectedItem -> SelectedAccount)
  - add-account button (Command -> AddAccountCommand)
  - determines how to display accounts,
    color-selection could be done with ValueConverters or data triggers

--------------------

DashBoardViewModel
  - Accounts property, a list of AccountViewModel objects
  - SelectedAccount, an AccountViewModel
  - AddAccountCommand, an ICommand that calls AddAccount on the model and refreshes Accounts
  - holds a reference to an AccountModel

AccountViewModel
  - wraps or represents an Account object
  - takes care of input validation
  - may contain additional properties to make editing or display easier

--------------------

AccountModel
  - AddAccount method, adds an account to the database
  - GetAccounts method, returns a collection of Account objects
  - perhaps an account-added event, if multiple VM's need to be informed

Account
  - holds account information
  - could be immutable, depending on how it is meant to be used
```

### Model class

Here are some more observations:

- Why does `QueryCommand` return a 'flat' list of values? Why not a list of records, or a `DataTable`? Hard-coding the column count is brittle.
- `UpdateBalance` creates an `AccountModel` object that isn't used.
- `SelectAccount` and `DeleteAccount` should not operate on a view. Keeping track of item selection and passing data to the model layer is a task for view-models.
- `Transaction` is a confusing name. It sounds like a database transaction, but it's actually a collection, and it's exposed directly to the view?
- Display colors are a responsibility of the view, not of the model.
- `TransType` should probably be an enum. Enums clearly indicate which values you can expect (a string could contain any text), which also helps 'documenting' the code.
- `SelectAccount` uses `for` loops, where `foreach` loops would be easier and more readable.
- Why does `DeleteAccount` create its own `Connection`? All other methods use the `conn` field.
- Where does `User._username` come from? The leading underscore makes it *look* like a private field, so that's odd. Either way, I assume it's a static field or property. Static things are essentially global, which means they can be accessed (and possibly changed) from anywhere. It also makes dependencies harder to spot. All that tends to make code more difficult to maintain. If `AccountModel` depends on a `User`, it should be passed in as a constructor or method argument (dependency injection).
- `Dispose` doesn't need to call `GC.SuppressFinalize` because your class doesn't have a finalizer (finalizers are rarely needed). There's no need for the full `Dispose(bool disposing)` pattern here.
- Why do `SelectAccount` and `DeleteAccount` call `LoadAccounts`? That seems like a lot of unnecessary work for a single change.

### View-model classes

- Personally I would group backing fields and properties together.
- Use `nameof(PropertyName)` instead of `"PropertyName"` to make things more refactor-proof, or use the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in your `OnPropertyChanged` method so you don't need to specify the property name at all.
- Why inherit from `ObservableCollection`? Why not just use an `ObservableCollection<AccountVM>` directly? The extra methods don't provide any additional functionality (especially `GetAccounts` - what's the idea behind that?).

And something that applies to both:

- Inconsistent naming: some private fields are prefixed with an underscore, others are not. Most method names use PascalCase, but some use camelCase. Try sticking to the standard C# naming conventions, and be consistent - it'll make code a little easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

From top to bottom review we will...

#### AccountModel

> ```
> private SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
> private AccountVM  accountVM = new AccountVM();
> ```

These variables aren't used and can be removed.

### AddNewAccount() and some other methods as well

Whenever you see a code snippet like

```
if (someCondition)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

you can simply return the codition itself like

```
public bool AddNewAccount(AccountVM account)
{
    return (conn.NonQueryCommand(accountTable.AddAccount(account.AccountType, account.AccountName, User._username, account.BankId, account.AccountNumber, account.StartingBalance, account.Balance)));
}
```

#### LoadAccounts()

Well `o` isn't really a descriptive name, is it? You should always name things as descriptive as possible. Assume you will come back to this code in 6 months because you have to fix a bug or add some functionality. You will spend a lot of time to understand the code again if you name things poorly.

The whole stuff about `numRecords`, `item`, `item1`, `item2`, ... could be rewritten like so

```
public Accounts LoadAccounts()
{
    List<string> o = conn.QueryCommand(accountTable.GetAccounts(User._username));
    Accounts accounts = new Accounts();

    for (int i = 0; i < o.Count; i += 7)
    {
        AccountVM accountVM = new AccountVM
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt16(o[i + 0]),
            AccountName = o[i + 1],
            AccountType = o[i + 2],
            Balance = Convert.ToDouble(o[i + 3]),
            StartingBalance = Convert.ToDouble(o[i + 4]),
            AccountNumber = o[i + 5]
        };

        accounts.addAccount(accountVM);
    }

    return accounts;
}
```

and now we see as well that the call of `conn.QueryCommand(accountTable.GetAccounts(User._username));` returns more than needed.

#### UpdateBalance()

See

> AddNewAccount() and some other methods as well

#### SelectAccount()

Using a guard check `if (accountVM == null) { return; }` will remove one level of indentation and the creation of

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
Accounts accounts = LoadAccounts();
LedgerModel ledgerModel = new LedgerModel();
```

isn't needed anymore for the case that the condition is true.

The loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
{
    if (accounts[i].Id == accountVM.Id)
    {
        accountVM.Balance = accounts[i].StartingBalance;
    }
}
```

looks a little strange, but I just assume there is at maximum one account with an `Id` equal to `accountVM.Id`. If `Accounts` would be a class which implements e.g `IEnumerable<T>` one could use `FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == accountVM.Id)` which would make it more obvious what is happening here.
**Edit:** I just noticed that `Accounts` is an `ObservableCollection<AccountVM>` hence using `FirstOrDefault()` should be the way to go.

At first glance it looks like the value of `accountVM.Balance` is overwritten each time.

The condition `if (transaction != null)` will **never ever** be `false`. You can safely remove it.

The coloring of the transactions should be moved inside a separate method.

Rewritten it would look like so

```
public void SelectAccount(DashBoardView dashBoard)
{
    AccountVM accountVM = (AccountVM)dashBoard.gridAccounts.SelectedItem;
    if (accountVM == null) { return; }

    Accounts accounts = LoadAccounts();

    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (accounts[i].Id == accountVM.Id)
        {
            accountVM.Balance = accounts[i].StartingBalance;
        }
    }

    LedgerModel ledgerModel = new LedgerModel();
    Transaction transaction = ledgerModel.LoadLedger(accountVM.Id, accountVM.AccountName);

    for (int i = 0; i < transaction.Count; i++)
    {

        transaction[i].Balance = ledgerModel.CalculateBalance(Convert.ToDouble(accountVM.Balance), transaction[i]);
        accountVM.Balance = transaction[i].Balance;

    }

    ColorTransaction(transaction);

    dashBoard.gridLedger.ItemsSource = transaction;
}  

private void ColorTransaction(Transaction transaction)  
{
    for (int i = 0; i < transaction.Count; i++)
    {
        if (transaction[i].TransType == "Withdrawal")
        {
            transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else if (transaction[i].TransType == "Deposit")
        {
            transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SteelBlue);
        }
        else
        {
            transaction[i].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

#### DeleteAccount()

In this method you don't bother that `AccountVM accountVM` may be `null`. Either it is possible then you should check it, or it isn't possible then you won't need the check in `SelectAccount()` as well.

Comment: I checked Pieter's comment bellow, but honestly both of these post were extremely helpful!